# Xamarin Forms Geolocator Continuously Updating the Location

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.forms, geolocation

**I'm looking to continuously update the device's current location on the Google Map.**

I have to implement my own *blue dot* for various reasons. What I have done is:

- I hide the Google Map's default *My Location* marker (*default blue dot*).
- I draw my own *blue dot*
- I created a thread that keeps calling the Geolocator to update its current position: `await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), null, false);`

However, the position update takes a significant delay. I am looking to update the position at a very low interval (around 50 ms) which could give me a similar result to the Google Map's original *blue dot* when the device is moving.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use your blue dot instead of default one? Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that `CrossGeolocator` has a *listening function* which will prompt if there is a position update. Rather than keep calling the current position, this function will continuously listen to any position changes.

```
if (CrossGeolocator.IsSupported &&
    CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable &&
    CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
{
    CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += HandlePositionChanged;
    await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 10);
}
```

Comment: The name 'HandlePositionChanged' does not exist in the current context ??

Comment: @MaddePersson that's your own function mate

Comment: Is there any equivalent available in Xamarin Essentials for PositionChanged subscription?